# Разбор url на кусочки

Tags: php

Доброго вечера. Есть урлы такого вида:

```
/katalog-ob-ektov/goryashchie-predlozheniya/item/na1029.html?category_id=21
/katalog-ob-ektov/apartamenty/item/na0123.html?category_id=2
```

Как через parse_url выдрать кусок после каталога объектов (например apartamenty) и занести в переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$path_parts = explode( '/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH) );
```

И делайте с $path_parts что хотите.